# Как из кода создать кнопку-картинку?

Tags: java, android

Привет всем! Такая тема: приложение при запуске должно получить с сервера целое число число n от 1 до 20, и после этого создать n кнопок-картинок, которые располагаются друг под другом(linear layout). Возможно ли такое вообще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, возможно. Варианты:

1) Неправильный:

В цикле создаёте

```
Button button = new Button(context);
yoursLinearLayout.addView(button);
```

2) Правильный:

Создайте `ListView`, адаптер к нему переопределите и добавляйте кнопки в `getView()` методе адаптера.

Comment: А разве можно в ListView поместить картинки?

Comment: Проще перечислить то, что туда нельзя поместить. Например другой ListView, ScrollView, GridView, TableView, RecyclerView. А всё остальное можно... Можно создать разметку почти любой сложности и поместить её в ListView. Например ВКонтакте, в приложении список новостей - это ListView, где каждая новость в отдельном элементе.